# PHP contact form emails to the email address, but 'name' field is empty?

Tags: php, html, forms

No, I am new to this form!

I have successfully set up a contact form page. It emails me the 'email address' and 'message' from the form fields, but does not send the name filed value, it is just blank.

I cannot see where I have gone wrong. All the field names match up to the PHP file. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
   <form id="form_28" name="website_query" action="mailform2.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:0;position:absolute;left:231px;top:242px;width:343px;height:229px; /*MainDivStyle*/" __AddCode="here">
<!--MainDivStart-->


<!-- HTML Frame - name txt_31 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:8px;width:51px;height:18px;overflow:hidden; /*BorderDivStyle*/" __AddCode="InsideBorderDiv">
<!--BorderDivContents-->
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><label for="edit_1"><span class="Body-C">name</span></label></p>
</div>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Form Edit box edit_1 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<input type="text" id="edit_1" name="name" value="" style="position:absolute; left:103px; top:8px; width:50px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here">
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- HTML Frame - email txt_32 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:38px;width:51px;height:18px;overflow:hidden; /*BorderDivStyle*/" __AddCode="InsideBorderDiv">
<!--BorderDivContents-->
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><label for="edit_19"><span class="Body-C">email</span></label></p>
</div>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Form Edit box edit_19 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<input type="text" id="edit_19" name="email" value="" style="position:absolute; left:103px; top:38px; width:50px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here">
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- HTML Frame - message txt_33 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:68px;width:79px;height:18px;overflow:hidden; /*BorderDivStyle*/" __AddCode="InsideBorderDiv">
<!--BorderDivContents-->
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><label for="text_2"><span class="Body-C">message</span></label></p>
</div>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Text Area text_2 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<textarea id="text_2" name="message" rows="2" cols="10" style="position:absolute; left:103px; top:68px; width:100px; height:38px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here"></textarea>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- HTML Frame - captcha txt_34 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:114px;width:69px;height:18px;overflow:hidden; /*BorderDivStyle*/" __AddCode="InsideBorderDiv">
<!--BorderDivContents-->
<p class="Wp-Body-P"><label for="captcha_1"><span class="Body-C">captcha</span></label></p>
</div>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Form CAPTCHA captcha_1 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:103px;top:114px;width:190px;height:69px; /*MainDivStyle*/" __AddCode="here">
<!--MainDivStart-->
    <img src="http://www.serifwebresources.com/util/img_verify.php?gen_word=1&id=captcha_1"><br><input type="text" id="captcha_1" name="captcha_1" size="20" __AddCode="here">
    <a title="Listen to audio CAPTCHA" href="http://www.serifwebresources.com/util/audio/audio.php"><img alt="Listen to audio CAPTCHA" style="vertical-align: middle" src="http://www.serifwebresources.com/media/icons/audio-desc.png" border="0"></a><!--MainDivEnd-->
</div>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Form Button butn_4 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<input type="submit" style="position:absolute; left:8px; top:191px; width:81px; height:22px; /*Tag Style*/" value="Submit" __AddCode="here">
<!--Postamble-->
</form>
```

code for PHP (mailform2.php):

```
  <?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 


if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Website Query: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
```

Comment: don't use name="name"

Comment: why? it worked for name="email" and name="message" just not sending the name

Comment: In the php manual itself there is an example of using name=name there is nothing wrong http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: What do you see if you dump your POST array, var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @Yellowledbet im not sure how to do that?

Comment: In your processing page comment out(add //) to your ' header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');' line. Then add var_dump($_POST); below it. Then submit a form and you should see the contents of the $_POST values

Comment: array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "lucy" ["email"]=> string(24) "lucywood2013@hotmail.com" ["message"]=> string(4) "hi" ["captcha_1"]=> string(6) "foiled" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))

$name = $_POST['name'];
```

In above code if post of name,email and message empty, then it set name = $_POST['name'];

SO $name variable not set.

So code like these

```
    if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
           empty($_POST['email']) || 
           empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $errors = 'Please enter all required fields';
    }
    else
    {
     $name = $_POST['name']; 
     $email = $_POST['email']; 
     $message = $_POST['message'];
   }
```

Comment: the issue is empty not this , you should use isset instead of empty it worked for me I have posted the correct code checkout @lucywood22

Comment: how would i include the captcha validation in php script?

Comment: I think capcha value stored as session, so in mailform2.php use session_start(); and check if($_SESSION['captcha'] === $_POST['captcha_1'])

Answer (score 0):

if your submiting, try to remove `value=''` just

```
<input type="text" id="edit_1" name="name" style="position:absolute; left:103px; top:8px; width:50px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here">
```

See if it works !

### *EDITED & ADDED*

change the sumbit's `value` into name to be: `name='submit'`

```
<input type="submit" style="position:absolute; left:8px; top:191px; width:81px; height:22px; /*Tag Style*/" name="submit" __AddCode="here">
```

and you may wanna change php part to look like this:

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail';//<-----Put Your email address here.

$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(isset($_POST['sumbit']) && (
    empty($_POST['name'])  ||
    empty($_POST['email']) ||
    empty($_POST['message'])))
    {
        echo "Please fill up the fields";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['sumbit']) && empty($errors)){
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Website Query: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message \n $message";

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: how would i validate captcha?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])  && !isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['message'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name']; 
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
   $message = $_POST['message']; 
}else{
   $errors = ''; //process
}
```

Add your curly braces. 
you are missing your curly braces. so the name variable is not being set if every POST variable has a value. The other two are because without the braces the if statement ends after the first statement.

Edit, I think your logic is wrong also. You probably want to say if all of these values are not empty then process.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here i debugged , here is the corrected working code . you have to use isset instead of empty there

```
<?php 

$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(isset($_POST['name'])  || 
   isset($_POST['email']) || 
   isset($_POST['message'])) { 


$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 


}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Website Query: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 


?>
```

Also I covered the if loop you can put mail sending code also inside the if loop there

Hope this helps